# How do we store file from remote server to object cloud storage?

Tags: java, cloud

How do we read file from remote server and stored it to cloud object storage using java

Comment: Did you google it?   
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java   
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries?topic=cloud-object-storage-java   
What cloud storage to you want to use?   
Also you must read    
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @tsotzolas Already I have been analyzed these links https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries?topic=cloud-object-storage-java, https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java. I want to know how do we retrieve file from remote server. I am having the java code for object storage.

Answer (score 0):

You need a cloud service.

Options:
 - AWS
 - Azure

We use AWS and their S3 storage service works great for files.
It expands in size automatically.

You can create an account that is free for 1 year, same with Azure.

You need a language to interface with the service. Alternatively, you could just use a GUI to login and upload the file to the cloud service. I use Cloudberry when I don't want to write code to upload files.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to store directly from remote server to cloud. Meanwhile without storing into any intermediate DB. Also I need write java code to upload file into cloud and I'm using IBM cloud object storage.

Comment: I didn't mention anything about storing the file in a database.